# Looking for a circuit to run a 12 V toilet exhaust fan when utility power fails

Tags: 12v, fan, backup

I have a tiny house.

Recently my inverter failed and it could take weeks or months to have it fixed. It's a 48 V DC solar to 240 V AC, that is intermittently working with a non-working 5 kWh battery.

When utility power fails and the toilet exhaust fan is not available, the result is an unbearably malodorous toilet.

The exhaust fan is powered by a 240 V AC to 12 V DC - 1 A power supply. I would like to have a simple circuit that would, in the absence of utility power, enable a 12 V car battery to power it.

I have a basic understanding of electrical circuits, but have never attempted to design any from scratch and instead always tried to adapt circuits that are similar.

What would be the best circuit for me to use so that I can keep the fan running?

I will charge the battery independent of this circuit, unless there is an easily adaptable solution for that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a simple SPDT relay. The mains power (12V from transformer) would drive the relay coil and also be fed through the normally open contact to power the fan. So, when the relay is "on" (mains power available), the fan would be powered from it. When mains power goes down and the relay shuts off, the battery 12V would then be directed to the fan through the normally closed contact.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is a very simple solution and after examining it, I feel confident I can implement it easily.  Thank you very much, I am most grateful.